# Docker live server does not render pages in my project directory

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. I'm creating a live reload server for a project folder that has static HTML files based on [this NPM package](http://tapiov.net/live-server/). This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:8.9.3-alpine
LABEL Name=app-static Version=1.0.0

# Configure container image
ENV NODE_ENV development
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME [ "app" ]
RUN npm install -g live-server@1.2.0
EXPOSE 1764
CMD [ "live-server", "--port=1764", "--entry-file=index.html" ]
```

This is what my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  app-static:
    image: app-static
    build: .
    ports:
      - 1764:1764
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, my container spins up and I get the following message in my terminal:

```
Serving "/app" at http://127.0.0.1:1764
```

When I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:1764/index.html though, I see the following message in my browser window:

> Cannot GET /index.html

Why is this happening? Looks like my project files aren't available to my container. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't [specified a mountpoint](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah! That was it. It works now. If you change your comment to an answer, I can mark it as an answer. Thanks.